# How this system transferred into this state variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Take a look at this transfer function:
$$
\frac{Y(s)}{U(s)} = \frac{1}{s^2 + 2s + 1} 
$$

The author of the book I'm reading says, the transfer function can be represented as

$$
\frac{Y(s)}{U(s)} = \frac{1}{s^2 + 2s + 1} = \frac{1}{(s+1)} \frac{1}{(s+1)}
$$

The block diagram is

[image]

Then the author states the following equations

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= x_2 - x_1 \\
\dot{x}_2 &= -x_2 + u \\
y &= x_1
\end{align}
$$
Notice: the last equation is given. I'm aware of the fact that state variables representation is not unique but I failed to understand this method. How did he come up with this representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct translation of the transfer relation is $(D+1)^2y=u$, with $D$ as the derivation operator. Now name the intermediate result $z=(D+1)y$ with consequently $(D+1)z=u$, then one can read this as a first order system
\begin{align}
y'&=-y+z\\
z'&=-z+u
\end{align}
which are the claimed equations.

The state here is $(y,z)$. If you want the systematic variables $\dot {\bf x}=f({\bf x},{\bf u})$, $y=g({\bf x},{\bf u})$, then you need to assign ${\bf x}=(x_1,x_2)$ to this state in some order, so that then $y$ only occurs as a function of the state ${\bf x}$

Comment: What are the choice of state variables in your solution? In the phase variable representation, we choose $x_1=y,x_2=\dot{y} \implies \dot{x}_1 = x_2, \dot{x}_2=u-2x_2-x1$.

Comment: The state is $(x,y)$. If you want the systematic variables $\dot {\bf x}=f({\bf x},u)$, $y=g({\bf x},u)$, then you need to assign ${\bf x}=(x_1,x_2)$ to this state in some order, so that then $y$ only occurs as a function of the state $(x_1,x_2)$

Comment: Something like this $x_1=(y-\dot{y}), x_2=(y+\dot{y})$?

Comment: No, just $y=x_1$, $x=x_2$. The systematic naming has the advantage that it is more systematic, and reduces the tendency to have multiple uses of the same letter in different roles.

Comment: I'm confused here. What does $x$ represent here in my question? The actual differential equation variable is $y$.

Comment: I've renamed the intermediary variable, so that $x$ only has one role now. Thus now $x_1=y$, $x_2=z$.

Comment: It seems the actual state variables are $x_1=y,x_2=(\dot{y}+y)$ this choice leads the exact same equations the author states.

Answer (score 2):

Calling $X_1(x)$ a variable between the two transfer blocks and $X_2(s)$ between the last transfer block and $Y(s)$ we have

$$
\cases{
X_1(s) = \frac{1}{s+1}U(s)\\
X_2(s) = \frac{1}{s+1}X_1(s)\\
Y(s) = X_2(s)
}
$$

and equivalently

$$
\cases{
\dot x_1 + x_1 = u\\
\dot x_2 + x_2 = x_1\\
y= x_2
}
$$

etc.

Answer (score -1):

Another answer for this problem beside the accepted answer. Let
$$
\begin{align}
x_1 &= y \tag{1} \\
x_2 &= \dot{y} + y \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
The actual dynamic equation is (i.e. this is given from the problem)
$$
\ddot{y} = u -2\dot{y} - y \tag{3}
$$

Taking the derivative of Eq(1) and Eq(2) with respect to time, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= \dot{y} \tag{4} \\
\dot{x}_2 &= \ddot{y} + \dot{y} \tag{5}
\end{align}
$$

From Eq(1) and Eq(4), we get
$$
\dot{x}_1 = x_2 - x_1 
$$

From Eq(3) and Eq(5) and Eq(2), we get
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_2 &= u -2\dot{y} - y + \dot{y} \\
&= u -\dot{y} - y  \\
&= u -(\dot{y} + y) \\
&= u - x_2
\end{align}
$$